# Difference between push/pull and shrink/fatten?

Tags: modeling, transforms

What's the difference between the push/pull and shrink/fatten tools in the transform menu in edit mode?

I noticed that they both do the same thing, so what's the point of making separate options?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They don't actually do the same things.

- [*Shrink/Fatten*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Deforming/Shrink-Fatten) scales the selected elements along their normals.

  [image]

  I've enabled face normals display in the above gif so that you can see that each face is moving along it's normal (blue lines).
- [*Push/Pull*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Advanced/Push_Pull) moves the selected elements farther/closer to the [pivot point](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point).

  [image]

  Here you can see that the faces are not moving along their normals, but instead are moving away from/closer to the pivot point. In this case, the pivot is the median location of the selected elements, which happens to be the world center in this particular example.