# Scale face by units rather than percent

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, transforms, faces

I'm trying to extrude a new face and shrink it by a *fixed number of units*, rather than a *percentage*.

Starting from something like this:
[image: Before]

I want to end up with this:
[image: Correct]

Note the distance between the original face and the new one is equal all round. I did this one by extruding the face, moving it a fixed numeric distance, then moving the 2 incorrect edges back double that distance. Obviously this only works for 90 degree edges, so less than ideal.

Using the normal scale method (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>) I get a percentage based result, like this:
[image: Percent]

I've seen two possible method of doing this, mianly from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/is-there-a-way-to-scale-by-an-absolute-distance-rather-than-a-percentage):

1. *Shrink / Fatten*: I've tried (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) for this, but the face just travels straight up and down - I assume the vertex normals are not correct for this approach.
2. *Push / Pull*: This is just apply percentage scaling for me at the moment.

If I actually extrude the face out a bit, then use Shrink / Fatten it works as expected, but I don't want to have to keep manually resetting heights.

Is there a quick way of scaling a face within it's normal, but by fixed units instead of axis percents?

---

**Edit:** @zeffii has pointed me in the direction of the *[Inset tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset)* (<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>).

Comment: What's wrong with `W -> Inset Faces` ? it accepts numeric input in Units.

Comment: Tested - absolutely nothing! I knew there would be something simple.. there are just so many features in Blender and I find it quite hard to Google for them sometimes - unless you already know the right names for things, they just don't come up! Thanks for this, please add it as a full answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: You can try to select the *Face* and press [*Inset Faces*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v1HFB.png) option in the *Toolshelf*.